# php and mysql variables

Tags: php, mysql, variables, post, while-loop

i have a web called [Infomundo](http://www.infomundo.org) and under the site i have a problem with php:

```
$c=1;
  while($c!=17)
  { $fecha_semana$c=$_POST['fecha_semana$c'];
    $interes_semana$c=$_POST['interes_semana$c'];
    $capital_semana$c=$_POST['capital_semana$c'];
    $recargos_semana$c=$_POST['recargos_semana$c'];
    $iva_semana$c=$_POST['iva_semana$c'];
    $pagado_semana$c=$_POST['pagado_semana$c'];
    $c=$c+1;
  }
```

but the variables $fecha_semana$c, $interes_semana$c, etc. are wrong how can i fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You're using single quotes in the array dereference:

```
$_POST['fecha_semana$c'];
```

That will not evaluate the value of `$c`; use double quotes:

```
$_POST["fecha_semana$c"];
```

See also: [`string`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)

Additionally, you need to use variable variables for the left hand of the assignment:

```
${"fecha_semana$c"} = $_POST["fecha_semana$c"];
```

**Update**

This problem would be easier if you'd use array syntax in your form fields:

```
<input name="fecha_semana[]" value="123" />
<input name="fecha_semana[]" value="456" />
<input name="fecha_semana[]" value="678" />
```

When that gets posted, you will have an array in PHP:

```
print_r($_POST['fecha_semana']);
// ["123", "456", "678"]
```

Comment: it still send me an error i used $fecha_semana$c=$_POST["fecha_semana$c"];

Comment: @user1932612 ah yes, updated answer; btw, it's a lot easier if you used array syntax in your form fields.

Comment: @user1932612 Glad to help; if this answer was adequate, consider to accept it by clicking the checkmark next to this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative option to Jack's solution, you can use concatention:

```
$_POST['fecha_semana'.$c];
```

I personally prefer concatenation as it is easier for me to see where variables are being used, but I would say it is largely a matter of preference.